# delayed audio in android

Tags: android

i'm trying to play audio when a button is clicked but there's some delay between when i press the button and when the audio is actually played. I get this error: `AudioFlinger(17396): write blocked for 162 msecs, 3 delayed writes, thread 0x15440` This is what i got so far:

```
ImageButton i = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button);
        i.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    s = new AudioPlayer(getApplicationContext());
                    s.playSound(R.raw.conga1);
            }
            return true;
            }
        });
```

**AudioPlayer class**

```
public class AudioPlayer {

  private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
  private final OnCompletionListener mediaPlayerListener = new MediaPlayerListener();
  private Context context = null;

  public AudioPlayer(Context context)
  {
    this.context = context;
    init();
  }

  private void init() {
    if (mediaPlayer == null) {
      AudioManager am = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
      int streamVolume = am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
      mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mediaPlayerListener);
      mediaPlayer.setVolume(streamVolume, streamVolume);
    }
  }

  private void setSound(int id) {
    if (mediaPlayer!=null) {
      mediaPlayer.reset();
      AssetFileDescriptor file = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(id);
      try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(file.getFileDescriptor(), file.getStartOffset(), file.getLength());
        file.close();
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        mediaPlayer = null;
      }
    }
  }

  public void playSound(int id) {
    if (mediaPlayer!=null) {
      setSound(id);
      mediaPlayer.start();
    }
  }

  private static class MediaPlayerListener implements OnCompletionListener {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
      mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Any clues?

Thanks in advance.

**EDITS:**
So i added a singleton and it helped but there's still delay. This is how it looks like now:

**AudioPlayer:**

```
public static synchronized AudioPlayer getSingletonObject(Context context, Uri pathToFile) {
    if (audioPlayer == null) {
        audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer(context, pathToFile);
    }
    return audioPlayer;
}

public void setSound(String pathToFile) {
    if (mediaPlayer!=null) {
        mediaPlayer.reset();

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(pathToFile);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } //catch....
    }
}

public void playSound(String path) {
    if (mediaPlayer!=null) {
        mediaPlayer.reset();

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            mediaPlayer.start();
        } //catch...
    }
}
```

**Main:**

```
final String path = "sdcard/myappsounds/snaredrum2.wav";
    final AudioPlayer s = AudioPlayer.getSingletonObject(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(path));
    s.setSound(path);

    ImageButton i = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button);
    i.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

                s.playSound(path);
        }
        return true;
        }
    });
```

Any ideas? What i'm trying to do is like a drumset, that's why the buttons must respond correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I/O on Android is *slow*. The audio subsystem is being forced to wait for it's data, and is kind enough to warn about it.

Rather than giving MediaPlayer a raw FileDescriptor (which will have no buffering applied) try using a file:// URI. With any luck the system content provider for file: will buffer it up for you the moment it's opened.

Comment: Would love to see some benchmarks on this - I'm sure you're right

Comment: i tried to do it as you said with no luck. It still plays delayed. Here's what i got: `mediaPlayer.setDataSource(pathToFile);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();` where `pathToFile` is a String. Any clues?

Comment: Are you giving a file:// URI?  If this doesn't work, call setDataSource() and prepare() before the button is pressed. That'll mean the data's all ready to play at the point is button is pressed.

Comment: check out my Edits, i did what you suggested but i don't get it to work.

Comment: You have not done what I suggested. I said to call setDataSource() and prepare() **before** the button is pressed. The only thing you want to do when the button is pressed is start().

Comment: Also, if what you're doing is "like a drumset", then presumably your recordings are suitably short? Like, less than a second? In which case SoundPool might be a much better choice than MediaPlayer.

Comment: I didn't know about `SoundPool` it performs better than `MediaPlayer` but if i press the button continuously faster, it fails. I guess i'm giving up soon. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The thing about SoundPool is, it keeps your audio samples decompressed and permanently in-memory. It's ideally suited to short sound effects, and not suited at all to (say) playing a 5 minute music track.

Comment: i went back to media player and did as you said. I did a method in the main activity to `setDataSource()` and `prepare()` the media player. Then in the button listener i did `mediPlayer.start()` it didn't work either. So i guess Android has bugs when it comes to handling audio?

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? MediaPlayer is probably the worst API in the whole Android SDK but I'd expect it to be able to play a little audio without issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know Android in depth, but from looking at this code what you could try is to use your `AudioPlayer` as a singleton and reuse your `MediaPlayer` instance?