# Is it possible to reduce the period between audio tracks being played with MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a number of audio tracks that I need to play in sequence. I'm using MediaPlayer's `OnCompletionListener` as follows:

```
public void OnCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
{
    _completed++;
    mp.Reset();

    if (_completed < _tracks.Length)
    {
        try
        {
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = _context.Resources.OpenRawResourceFd(_tracks[_completed]);

            if (afd != null)
            {
                mp.SetDataSource(afd.FileDescriptor, afd.StartOffset, afd.Length);
                afd.Close();
                mp.Prepare();
                mp.Start();    
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but there is a noticeable delay between tracks. I'd like to reduce that period to as close to zero as possible. Is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552810/delayed-audio-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MediaPlayer "chaining" was added with API level 16 (Jellybean). The method you'd be interested in is [`setNextMediaPlayer(MediaPlayer next)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setNextMediaPlayer%28android.media.MediaPlayer%29):

> Set the `MediaPlayer` to start when this `MediaPlayer` finishes playback (i.e. reaches the end of the stream). The media framework will attempt to transition from this player to the next as seamlessly as possible. The next player can be set at any time before completion. The next player must be prepared by the app, and the application should not call `start()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Not with the standard android player though there were many requests to add gapless playback - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3461

You can try to create and prepare a second instance of MediaPlayer and switch them quickly in the OnCompletion callback.